# How do I change a value of a domain class in view page

Tags: grails

I have an admin Domain class and I am trying to change its variable `pass` since it is set to a default value `admin123`

As I was reading in Grails documentation I read about `remoteField` that it could change the value in a domain class, however nothing happens when I enter a new value in the text field and click enter.

Here is my Admin domain class with `pass` as variable and `changePassword` as the function that should be called in the `remoteField`

```
class Admin {
    String pass = "admin123"

    static constraints = {
        pass size: 5..15, blank: false
    }

    def changePassword() {
        def a = new Admin()
        a.pass = params.value
        a.save()
     }
}
```

and this is the changePassword.gsp which allows admin to change his password

```
<h5>Your old password is "${oldPass}"</h5>
<h3>Please input your new password</h3>
<g:remoteField action="changePassword" name="pass" value="${admin?.pass}" />
```

and this is the Admin controller method of `changePassword` to show the `oldPass`

```
def changePassword = {
    def admin = new Admin()
    def oldPass = admin.pass
    [oldPass: oldPass]  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.4/ref/Tags/remoteField.html) for `remoteField`, you'll see that it sends an event when it changes. When this changes, it posts the value to the action `changePassword`. In `changePassword`, the default param name is `value`. So something like..

```
def admin = Admin.get(params.id);
admin.pass = params.value;
admin.save(flush: true, failOnError: true);
```

This will save the admin object.

**NOTE**

You're saving a password in plaintext. Don't do this. You should be hashing the password before storage. To do this, you can add a `beforeInsert` event hook into your domain object.

```
def beforeInsert() {
    this.pass = // You can work this out. Hash the password!
}
```

**EDIT**

From the docs.

> This tag creates an input field that fires an AJAX request when its value changes (typically when the user presses return inside the field).

The event is fired when the user hits enter inside of the field, or the value changes. There is no need for a submit button. This does not submit anything. It is an AJAX POST.

Comment: But should I add a submit button under the remoteField for it to take the information ? could you edit that in your answer